# WSL Ubuntu Distro | How to solve `Operation not permitted` on cloning repository

Tags: git, chmod, windows-subsystem-for-linux, clone

I am running Ubuntu 18.04, as a Subsystem for Windows. I have done this in mutliple PCs and never had this problem. I try to to `git clone <repo>`, and I get this:

```
Cloning into '<repo>'...
error: chmod on /mnt/c/Users/Efsta/Code/<repo>/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted
fatal: could not set 'core.filemode' to 'false'
```

I tried the following:

1. `❯ git config core.fileMode false`, with this result
   `fatal: not in a git directory`
2. `❯ git config --global core.filemode false`
3. `❯ git config --add --global core.filemode false`

Nothing seems to work. I already tried a couple of answers here, but WSL seems a little bit more tricky. Anyone have any idea about how to solve this?

I have also tried everything in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes, nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`/mnt/c/Users/...` is on the Windows NTFS partition itself, and not within the WSL's `ext4` formatted system.  Therefore you have to treat it as you would an NTFS partition on a USB stick on an actual Ubuntu installation, and accept the limitations of NTFS.

NTFS partitions **do not support `chmod` or similar Linux permissions commands**, and unlike in actual Ubuntu instalations which don't error but don't make any permissions changes, WSL doesn't relay this information back to you, it simply errors out as you see here.

You cannot do a `git clone` sanely into the `/mnt/c/...` space within WSL because of the Linux permission schemas and `chmod` not working right.  This is a limitation of WSL in its current form.

Comment: Ok let me confirm some things. Microsoft says, that I should develop in WSL within Windows, so I can modify them on both the WSL and Windows sides. So, in every other installation I had until now, I did the same.

And if we assume that what youa re saying is correct, what would you recommend as a soution to my problem?

Comment: And to add to my above question. What do I do about ssh? Can I resuse the same key on both. There are situations like `gcloud` where I want to use my windows deve enviroment instead...

Comment: Also, previously I was using WLinux, which was slow, but witht the same underlying theory used the Windows filesystem, and I could do it as well. So, not an Ubuntu specific thing.`Sorry for spamming you`

Comment: @DimitrisEfst you should be using the in-built Linux partitions within WSL and not `/mnt/c/Users/...` or such.  This is, again, a WSL limitation.  (That is, use your `/home/USER/...` directory stored within Ubuntu WSL for *nix permissions and copy built binaries, etc. out into `/mnt/c/Users/...` for use in the Windows native environment.  (There's a lot of limitations for WSL though, so keep that in mind)

Comment: This answer may have been accurate at the time it was written but isn't any more. I clone repos from WSL into /mnt/c/ all the time without any problems, with obvious usability benefits over cloning into ~/. See Wojtek's answer instead.

Comment: @Justin, honestly, I don't even think it was accurate back then. I have always used git to clone in /mnt/c on windows 10 since 2019, and it always worked just fine. Recently I faced this on a different win 11 pc, which is why I am here, but still managed to solve it.

Answer (score 141):

I had the same issue. Try this:

```
sudo umount /mnt/c
sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c -o metadata
```

Change the drive letter to whatever one you're having the issue with.

Comment: The command was successful but this did not change the issue for me. I still see "operation not permitted" as git tries to chmod .git/config.lock.

Comment: Worked for me. Is there some reason MS is not doing this when they mount windows locations automatically?

Comment: Note that this is available after build 17063: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-17063

Comment: This is working for me at the moment

Comment: confirmed this fixed the issue for me - had to change directory from windows file system to ubuntu to get the unmount command to work, but after running the commands, i was able to `git clone` my repo without permissions issue

Comment: This works as of WSL 2 in Windows 10 2004

Comment: Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I am using WSL2 and this does not work similar to @akohlsmith 's scenario. However, I find out that mounting as a normal user will work: `sudo mount -t drvfs C:\\folderVolume /mnt/folderVolume -o metadata uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=22,fmask=111`. Now I can do `chmod` without any issue.

Comment: Did the trick for me!

Comment: Saved my day, thank you so much. For some reason I haven't found it anywhere regarding my particular issue, but I started to look at similar issues and finally stumbled upon this one! What a luck :)

Comment: @Valorad has the correct addition in their comment - adding the uid and gid are necessary to avoid the file's owner being root. Note that a comma is needed between the metadata and uid options though.

Answer (score 101):

You can automatically mount your Windows drives under WSL with the metadata option that allows apps, like git, to use chmod and fix this issue.

Edit `/etc/wsl.conf` (create it if it doesn't exist).
Add the following:

```
[automount]
options = "metadata"
```

Then either:

- Reboot Windows
- Exit any WSL sessions, run `wsl --shutdown` from PowerShell or CMD, and start WSL again
- Exit your only session, terminate it with `wsl --terminate <distroName>`, and start it again,

Then never worry about it again.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me in combination with re-mounting the drive.

Comment: I had to restart my computer after doing this.

Comment: Instead of rebooting, with WSL 2 you can exit out of all WSL 2 shells, and then run `wsl --shutdown` from powershell instead. When you start a new WSL shell, it'll automatically start the underlying VM again with your new config.

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you!

Comment: The savior we need! thanks :)

Comment: Just did this on WSL2 and it worked, shutdown WSL2 via powershell, no reboot required.

Comment: worked as a charm, should be accepted answer

Comment: Worked for me too. Ideal, as I'm often generating pdfs and zips for upload via web forms.

Answer (score 10):

I was having the same issue. My solution is to git clone my repo in the default WSL location (it works), and use Visual Studio Code to remote access my WSL's repos. That way you won't have to use /mnt/c at all.

Links: 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl